# How to convert multiple .py files into .exe and run them in a sequence?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two python files 
1) main file which doing the work a
2)Running unittests for main file.

I want to convert them into an .exe file such that whenever .exe run it will execute the unittest file first then main file.Any help or suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0):

So what I would recommend doing in this case is having the unit test be called inside of the main file, so that if you were to run the main file itself; it would run the unit test; then once you have done this use `cx_Freeze` and write a script, making sure you include your unit test as a module within the script.

cx_Freeze documentation can be found here: https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/